# Semantic web, datatypes and sparql. (Is the return type arbitrarily)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I've found the semantic web dynamically typed!  For example I've been querying for the birthdays and I have until now got found `xsd:Integer`s.  However, now I've received an `xsd:date` when querying for a different person.  How do you handle this problem when used from a statically typed language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section [4.3 Infobox Data](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets?v=bli#h18-11) from the DBpedia wiki, the triples using properties in the `dbpprop` namespace (`http://dbpedia.org/property/`) are much dirtier:

> You should therefore use the infobox dataset only if your application requires complete coverage of all Wikipeda properties and you are prepared to accept relatively noisy data.

You'll get much more consistent data with properties from the `dbpedia-owl` (`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`) namespace:

> the instance data within the infobox ontology is much cleaner and better structured than the Infobox Dataset

For instance, if you grab 20 birthdates using `dbprop:dateOfBirth`, you'll get integers and dates:

```
SELECT distinct ?date WHERE { 
  ?x dbpprop:dateOfBirth ?date 
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+distinct+%3Fdate+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fx+dbpprop%3AdateOfBirth+%3Fdate+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
date
"1908"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
1946-03-14
1951-06-15
"1984"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
1878-11-09
"24"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
"21"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
"2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
"14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
1922-02-10
```

Using `dbpedia-owl:birthDate` give much more consistent results:

```
SELECT distinct ?date WHERE { 
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?date 
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+distinct+%3Fdate+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fx+dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate+%3Fdate+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
date
0001-01-01
0001-03-12
0005-02-27
0012-08-31
0012-12-07
0015-09-24
0016-09-16
0019-05-26
0019-11-25
0030-11-08
```

That said, there's still *some* noise in the data.  For instance, here's a query that tells us what datatypes the object of `dbpedia-owl:birthDate` have, and for each type, the number of times that `dbpedia-owl:birthDate` has an object of that type, and an example object of that type that appears as the object of `dbpedia-owl:birthDate`.

```
SELECT ?datetype (COUNT(?date) as ?numberOfType ) (SAMPLE(?date) as ?exampleDate )WHERE { 
  [] dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?date .
  BIND ( datatype( ?date ) as ?datetype )
}
GROUP BY ?datetype
ORDER BY DESC(?numberOfType)
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fdatetype+%28COUNT%28%3Fdate%29+as+%3FnumberOfType+%29+%28SAMPLE%28%3Fdate%29+as+%3FexampleDate+%29WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%5B%5D+dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate+%3Fdate+.%0D%0A++BIND+%28+datatype%28+%3Fdate+%29+as+%3Fdatetype+%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fdatetype%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC%28%3FnumberOfType%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
datetype                                    numberOfType  exampleDate
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date       608771        0001-01-01
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay    1185        "--02-29"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string        246        "--01-01"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
```

Most of the dates are `xsd:date`s.  I'm not sure why an `xsd:gMonthDay` appears an example of an `xsd:string`.